# i need to create a autocomplet combobox using php mysql and jqwey

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i need some help please.
i have a data base that has a 100 row one of the field call name i need to create a **autocomplet combobox** so the user can click on it so it will show all the list with a scroll so he can select one of them or he can search the name by typing the name in that **autocomplet combobox** if the result more that 10 it will show a ***scroll*** so he can select one of them
using **php, mysql and jquery**

thanks a lot.

Comment: http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/jquery-php-mysql-ajax-autocomplete/

Comment: I can't even read this question.

Comment: I was going to edit this question to make it easier to read.  I can't decipher it enough to modify it without totally changing what the submitter is trying to express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a few minutes to understand what you are looking for. You'll get a greater response if you word your question better and used some punctuation!

Anyway, here's what you're looking for (i think): [jQuery combobox using PHP and MySQL](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/phpintegration/bind-jquery-combobox-to-mysql-database-using-php.htm)